# Get Object Label from API Name in LWC using wire

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

Is there any way to get Object label from API Name?
I tried Below, but it gives API Name Only

```
import objectName from '@salesforce/schema/object';
```

Answer (score 19):

Salesforce should provide easy way to get the standard object labels without necessarily using ui api.

With UI api one can get the label as below

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title={objectInfo.data.label} icon-name="standard:account">
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS file

```js
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

export default class ObjectLabel extends LightningElement {
    @api objectApiName;
    @track objectInfo;
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;
}
```

The other alternative would be to write an apex class that can return the object label taking object api name as parameter and then use @wire service to display on lwc frontend .